# How can I select all element's childs except specific ones?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Here is my code:

```css
div{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a>link</a>
  <span>something</span>
  <p>paragraph</p>
  there is also some explanations
</div>
```

I want to apply that `red` color only to whatever which is in `div` tag except `a` and `<span>` tags. So in this case just `paragraph` and `there is also some explanations` should be red.

How can I do that?

Comment: downvoter what's wrong with my question?

Comment: I haven't voted on this question but `color` is an inherited property, so you'd have to override it for the elements that don't need it. Or you should wrap the *there is also some explanations* text within a different element of its own.

Comment: This is a good question.  If anything, whoever downvoted your question probably did so because no attempted solutions were provided.  I don't think it's really needed here, though.

Comment: You're not looking to select some child elements and exclude others here, since you're interested in also coloring the text content that *doesn't* reside in a child element. You just don't want the text in the a and span elements to be affected. So select those and apply the base color. No need to complicate things.

Answer (score 1):

### Edited:

With this CSS, you make the `<div>`s's childrens red and then you make the `<a>`s and the `<span>`s black:

```
div {
  color: red;
}
div>a,span {
  color: black;
}
```

Check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) site for CSS selectors. It explains how to select elements in different ways.

Comment: This will leave "there is also some explanations" not red.  Not that I have any better ideas.

Comment: @JosephMarikle - Because that isn't in a element. How about `div{color:red}` and `div>a,span{color:black}` then?

Comment: Yes your edited version can be a workaround. thank you .. upvote

Comment: The `>` will only point to the first `a` and `span` elements which CSS finds inside your element.

Comment: @Sqnkov - I can have multiple `<a>`s and `<span>`s inside the `<div>` and it works. As long as the `<div>` is their [parent](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_gt.asp).

Comment: @stack - Glad to help! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can reset then to `initial`

```css
div {
  color: Red;
}
div * {
  color: initial;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a>link</a>
  <span>span</span>
  <p>paragraph</p>
  there is also some explanations
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe it should be noted to the OP that `div *` is a selector for all children elements in a `div`

Answer (score 0):

> ***You must apply CSS's best practices of using classes on all of your elements. It will save you time and it will improve your performance at some point of your developer training.***

---

Always try to keep Your code ***as lean as poissible***. Do not over-indulge in complex selectors, unless you really need to.

---

If you continue to struggle using base element selectors in a larger project, you will experience a lot of headaches trough your development process.

So I suggest that you stick to this approach.

```css
div .otherExpl {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a>link</a>
  <span>something</span>
  <p>paragraph</p>
  <div class="otherExpl">there is also some explanations</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Sqnkov, but sometimes we need a really specific selector.
So what you need is something like this.

This snippet will for the first level if you want this to work for nested
nodes then use `div *:not(span):not(a)`

You should also be more specific with your selectors since `<div>` is a generic selector and give it some specific class like `.div_red_color`.

```css
div > *:not(span):not(a){
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a>link</a>
  <span>something</span>
  <p>paragraph</p>
  <div class="otherExpl">there is also some explanations</div>
</div>
```